# How to enable RDP or VNC on Ubuntu through CLI

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, rdp

I have a desktop running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, I have SSH enabled however I would like to also manage the computer either through VNC or RDP. I looked through a couple of forums on the internet however all the solutions didn't seem to work. My Ubuntu computer is currently not connected to any monitor/peripherals so I would need to enable these settings through the CLI.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at x11vnc? I use that with RealVNC Viewer. It may suit your needs.

Comment: FYI:  I'd check your system is *up-to-date* as a fully upgraded 18.04 system will report as 18.04.5, to report as 18.04.4 implies you've not upgraded fully since before 13-August-2020 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/)